# GetStream.io filter activities by an extraField

Tags: flutter, kotlin, getstream-io

I have some posts in a feed, with an extra field like "moderated":0 or 1

I need to get the activities where extra field "moderated" = 1 only

Is there any filter on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your moderated activities to a separate feed. Then you can easily return them with an API call.